# .png not being properly created from plot

Tags: r, plot, png, tiff

I have several tif files created with Rstudio from species occurrence maps. Because I want to use these files as a proper image of the occurrences on a map, I have to convert my tif files to a png.

I created a script where I load all my tif files into Rstudio. Then change the color chart of the tif to a viridis chart via the viridis package and then plot it. Afterwards, the plot should be saved in my working directory as a png. However, no files are created?

```
library(raster)
library(viridis)

# set working directory to the folder containing the TIF files

# get list of TIF files in the working directory and its subfolders
tif_files <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.tif$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

# loop over each TIF file
for (file_path in tif_files) {
  # read TIF file
  raster_obj <- raster(file_path)
  
  # get species name from file name
  species_name <- gsub(".tif", "", basename(file_path))
  
  # plot raster
  plot(raster_obj, col = viridis(100))
  
  # save plot as JPG file using the original species name
  png(file = paste0(species_name, ".png"), width = 800, height = 600, res = 450)

  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Try moving the png() call to before the plot(). I believe the plotting needs to happen between the png and dev.off()

Comment: I tried but got this error: ```Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large```

However. If I move the png() call before the plot(), will the viridis color chart then be used in the output because it is used after the png() call?